# Downloading a file using React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, single-page-application

I am trying to build a single page app using React. I came up with this hacky way to download a local file (residing in the `public` directory). I have two questions:

1. Can I write this more cleanly?
2. Is there any better or more elegant way to download a local file?

```js
const handleDownload = () => {
  const tempComponent = document.createElement('a')
  tempComponent.href = 'Dark.ask'
  tempComponent.download = 'Dark.ask'
  tempComponent.click()
  tempComponent.parentElement?.removeChild(tempComponent)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`1`. No, it's always the same process: create link element, put encoded (base64, urlencoded) data to the link, programmatically click the link and then remove element

`2`. I think, better you should not place all data to `href` attribute of `a` element - it's all will be loaded to user ram.

Use stream saver: https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js
It will allow you to download any size of file from custom source (like API endpoint)

---

Or you can just put a link to the static file in `[href]`, and when the user clicks the link, the browser will automatically start download, more: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp.

---

maybe duplicate of [How to download large file with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932213/how-to-download-large-file-with-javascript)